# $A, B$ --- enumerable sets, is $A \times B$ enumerable?

Tags: computability, discrete-mathematics

$A, B$ – enumerable sets, is $A \times B$ enumerable?
I have some thoughts, that maybe it can be done using something like the proof of countability of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, but I don't know how to prove this more proper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways you could solve this, so here's a hint. $A$ and $B$ are enumerable, which means that injections

$$ f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \quad \text{and} \quad g : B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$

exist. Now, given a tuple $t \in A \times B$, how can you map it to a unique element in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ using $f$ and $g$?

> Since $f$ and $g$ are injections, their product must also be an injection (prove this). So the function $h : A \times B \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, defined as $(a, b) \mapsto (f(a), g(b))$. Is an bijection on a subset of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ (because it is an injection on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$).

A subset of an enumerable set is always countable, so this concludes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots$ be an enumeration of $A$, and let $b_0,b_1,b_2,\ldots$ be an enumeration of $B$. Then one enumeration of $A \times B$ is
$$
(a_0,b_0), \\
(a_0,b_1),(a_1,b_0), \\
(a_0,b_2),(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_0), \\
\ldots
$$
See if you can turn this idea into a full-fledged proof.